# Error when running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am following Michael Hartl's rails tutorial. Everything was working fine, but when I run "rails server" on the command line I get the following error:

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/home/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-    3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:254:in `merge': can't convert String into Hash (TypeError)
from /home/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:254:in `root'
from /home/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1321:in `root'
from /home/jonathan/Desktop/railsTut/sample_app/config/routes.rb:4:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /home/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:289:in `instance_exec'
from /home/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:289:in `eval_block'
from /home/jonathan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:267:in `draw'
from /home/jonathan/Desktop/railsTut/sample_app/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
.
.
.
```

Here is my routes.rb file

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  root  'static_pages#home'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy',     via: 'delete'
  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

 end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As you can see, error points to fourth line of your `config/routes.rb` file. We won't be able to help unless you show contents of your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Apologies - I just posted it

Answer (score 3):

In your line 4 of `routes.rb` you should have:

```
root to: 'static_pages#home'
```

The error occurs because, as you see [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base/root), `root` method expect its parameter to be `Hash` while you are passing `String`.

Comment: It seems that `root 'static_pages#home'` is fine in Rails 4, but not in Rails 3.2.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
root to: 'static_pages#home'
```